# Simple FTP server for OSX

Tags: osx, ftp

I'm looking for a good OS X alternative for [Baby FTP Server](http://www.pablosoftwaresolutions.com/html/baby_ftp_server.html), an easy to use Window applications that allow you to transfer (large) files easily through established network protocols.

**Context**:

I regularly need to transfer large files from my laptop to either other client machines or servers. These servers could be any OS (primarily Windows or Linux) and are usually locked down in a way that you can't install applications and that the firewall will block incoming connections (thus no setting up a temporary HTTP or FTP server on that side).

Normally I opt for the HTTP server available through Python (as described [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python)), but for very large files (several GB), an HTTP transfer is not ideal (e.g. IE tends to get a bit *wonky*).

Because of this, I'd like a simple OSX app that creates an FTP server with (almost) no configuration.

**Requirements**:

- Easy to use application: the lesser the number of configuration options the better
- GUI (preferably with an OSX look and feel)

**Extra points for**:

- Native applications
- Single application (vs. a CLI server app and an additional, separate GUI app)
- Upload ability

**Not required**:

- User accounts (anonymous transfer is fine)

**Disqualified**:

- Built-in FTP server (as there's no GUI without purchasing the Server.app, which really is a bit much for what I'm after)
- FTP servers available through homebrew (i.e. proftpd, pure-ftpd and vsftpd) as they have no GUI available (I know [PureFTPd Manager](http://jeanmatthieu.free.fr/pureftpd/) is available but it hasn't been updated for some time now)